# cakephp 3 multiple Auth login

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

i have 3 different types of users : website users,Sponsors and Admin, each one associated to a table. I can't merge the tables since they have different fields.

I would like to use 3 different auth, how can I do?

Controller name 
1. UsersController
2. SponsorsController
3. AdminsSController

please can you sent to me sample code or guide lines how can do in cakephp 3.x.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The way that I've handled similar situations is to have a simple users table that includes only the common fields (e.g. username, name, password, email), and then that table contains sponsor, admin, etc. records. A little bit different database structure, and can admittedly a little bit tricky to get the creation and association of those records working correctly, but the result simplifies all your auth-related checks.

Comment: Just create a user_type field in your database table, then add your type cakephp has an easy blog tutorial. 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#blog-tutorial-authentication-and-authorization

Comment: I would keep it all the same, and either redirect afterwards based on the role OR switch the content displayed and forms etc based on that role. This is less error prone usually than splitting login URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it. You can simply create admin_panel and sponsors_panel folders under your /src/Controllers folder.

Then create related controller in those folder and define routing in /confing/routes.php as per your website for e.g.

```
Router::prefix('admin_panel', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Admin', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::prefix('sponsors_panel', function ($routes) {

        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Sponsors', 'action' => 'login']);
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });
```

Then you can access your login panels using

http://www.example.com/sponsors_panel

http://www.example.com/admin_panel